# Comma seperated file that I want to load into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a comma seperated file, a row looks like:

"ABC234234", 23

I want to load this into a dictionary, with the key being the first part i.e. "ABC234234"

I have to remote the double quotes also.

What's the pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: I don't know, offhand, but this would likely be a good place to start: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: Is this a CSV file, or just a handcrafted file format that looks as you've described? How robust does this have to be with regards to lines that look slightly different? Can the key contain commas?

Comment: There is only 1 comma per line.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest (like always) opening the CSV file with the `with` statement (which **ensures** it *will* be closed when you're done!) -- apart from that, @carl's answer is generally fine:

```
import csv

with open('yourfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    thedict = dict(csv.reader(f))
```

and then freely use `thedict` as you require.

Note that the values (as well, of course, as the keys) will be *strings*.  If you know that the second column always has an integer, and want to have `int`s as values, you could replace the assignment with

```
    thedict = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in csv.reader(f))
```

or, if you prefer to avoid excessive compactness/density in your code, decompose this latest statement into, for example:

```
    ks_vs = ((k, int(v)) for k, v in csv.reader(f))
    thedict = dict(ks_vs)
```

or break it down even further, if you wish, of course.

This works in Python 2.6 or better.  If you're stuck with 2.5, to make it work, add

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

at the top of the module -- the rest of my advice still applies;-).

Comment: I have to strip the double quotes also.  Oh and the file I am getting is actually downloaded using urllib2 from the web, so its not on disk.

Comment: @Blankman, (1): part of cvs's work is removing quotes from around fields that are in quotes -- have you _tried_ it before complaining?-)  (2): The result of `urllib2.urlopen` is a file-like object and it's perfectly suitable to pass as argument to `csv.reader`, just like the result of `open` (an actual file object) is.

Answer (score 4):

```
import csv
d = dict(csv.reader(open("foo.txt", "rb")))
```

Comment: Always open files for use with `csv.reader` with `mode='rb'` (Python 2.x) or `newline=''` (Python 3.x)

Comment: I used to do this with a `for` loop. Never knew dict could do this. (But then again I only started learning Python 2 months ago :P )

Comment: This answer would be better if you closed the file explicitly. To match the power of `with` you should use a `try/finally` to ensure the file is closed even if there is an exception from `csv.reader` for example

Answer (score 3):

You asked for **Pythonic**. If you wish to follow one of the precepts in the Zen of Python ("Errors should never pass silently") and you want to check that there are no duplicate keys in your data, or do other error checking or sanitising (examples: key can't be an empty string, want to strip leading/trailing whitespace), you'll need to write more detailed code.

```
#untested example
import csv
with open('the_file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    the_dict = {}
    for rownum, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
        if len(row) != 2:
            error('row length is not 2', rownum, row)
            continue
        k, v = [item.strip() for item in row]
        if not k:
            error('key is empty string', ...); continue
        if k in the_dict:
            error(...); continue
        the_dict[k] = v
```

Comment: much more straight forward, with the ability to modify as I insert into the dic (more readable rather).